# Controller for @OneToMany relationship using Spring Boot

Tags: java, database, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to figure out with Spring Boot and databases.

So I have 2 entities with `@OneToMany` relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Team {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int teamId;

    @Column
    private String teamTitle;

    @Column
    private String teamCity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "conferenceId", nullable = false)
    private Conference teamConference;

    public Team() { super(); } 

//some getters and setters
    }
```

And the second one:

```
@Entity
public class Conference {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int conferenceId;

    private String conferenceTitle;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teamId")
    private List<Team> conferenceTeams;

    public Conference() {
        super();
    }

//some getters and setters
}
```

Jsp page:

```
<body>
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="team">
  <div>
    <form:label path="teamTitle">Title</form:label>
    <form:input path="teamTitle" type="text"/>
    <form:label path="teamCity">City</form:label>
    <form:input path="teamCity" type="text"/>

    //DAHELL IS HERE
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="conferenceList">Select conference:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="conferenceList">
        <c:forEach items="${conference}" var="conf">
          <option>${conf.conferenceTitle}</option>
        </c:forEach>
      </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
  </div>
</form:form>

// jquery etc
</body>
```

And controller class:

```
@Controller
public class TeamsController {

@Autowired
private TeamDAO teamDAO;

@Autowired
private ConferenceDAO conferenceDAO;

@RequestMapping(value = "/schedule", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showSchedule(ModelMap model) {

    model.put("conferences", conferenceDAO.findAll());
    model.put("teams", teamDAO.findAll());
    return "schedule";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/new-team", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addNewTeam(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("conference", conferenceDAO.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("team", new Team());
    return "new-team";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/new-team", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTeam(ModelMap model, Team newTeam) {
    teamDAO.save(newTeam);
    return "redirect:/schedule";
}
}
```

ConferenceDAO and TeamDAO are just interfaces extended from JpaRepository.

So what I'm trying to understand is how to add new `Team`. I insert title and city through `jsp` page and also I should choose which conference this team belongs. But when I press `add` button I got

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available
```

What am I doing wrong? I believe that something with `selecting` part in `jsp` page. And I'm 100% sure I'm missing something in my `Controller` class. Somehow I should save new team to my DB and the `Conference` column also should show that it contains this new team.
I'd really appreciate guys if you show me the way to dig up.

Comment: please include the whole stack trace

Comment: debug and find out at what place you get error? and where is action in the form?

Comment: Probably cannot create a team for the addTeam post method. You should probably just start with the stacktrace instead of so much code when you are not sure what the problem is. Thanks. Please see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, comments really helped. So for those who read it - sleep on the problem and read logs before ask dumb questions (as I did :D )
The problem was within `jsp` page and `selection` form. I was getting `Null` for `conferenceId` and I would know it if I'd read logs.
So comments about checking whole stack trace and changing `jsp` selection part - worked for me.

Fixed `jsp` selection is:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="conferenceList">Select conference:</label>
  <form:select path="teamConference" id="conferenceList">
      <form:options items="${conference}" itemLabel="conferenceTitle"/>
  </form:select>
</div>
```

Thx guys!